# how to add expand/collapse tree in left sidebar navigation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365, office-web-apps

I want to create an internal online help documentation for a tool in my organisation. The documentation spans across multiple pages so I want to add an expandable/collapsible navigation tree in left sidebar similar to [this](https://developer.arm.com/docs/100769/latest/target-setup/features-of-streamline-ultimate-professional-and-community-editions). 
Any way do do this in sharepoint/Office 365 enterprise edition 2016.

Any other suggestions/tips to create great online documentation with sharepoint  will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Are you currently using any customized Themes? If you are using Doc Theme,then maybe you could try this:
1-Go to Space admin -> Themes
2-Go into Documentation Theme configuration
3-Un-select Page Tree
4-Add something similar to the following to navigation
1
{pagetree:startDepth=3|searchBox=true}

Or if you are familiar with boot strap , You can try. look at this link.

http://bootply.com/88026
```